# How do I get the password-text-box eye to work in all password text boxes?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I absolutely LOVE this feature.  There is never anyone around to see it when I click on it so it is not any hazard at all.

I am finding that it does not seem to run on all password text boxes.  Is there any rhyme or reason for this?  Is it an ad-on that can be applied to other browsers?

Is there a name for it other than Password-text-box eye?

At first I thought is was a phisher and every time I revealed my password I imagined that it was sending my username and password somewhere. (-:

Comment: It's the first time I see someone posting how great this feature is. And it is indeed, because 'password dots' give you an illusion of security while the password is still kept in RAM in plain text. I've seen some questions about entirely *disabling* that feature before, maybe the opposite option will be somewhere near to that one.

Answer (score 1):

The textboxes you are seeing this in are Internet Explorer 10 rendering a standard HTML [input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) tag with it's [type](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) set to "password".

If there are certain password boxes on pages where this doesn't work, it probably isn't a standard HTML input box with its type set to password.

To get it to work on these types of pages would require changes by the owner.

Comment: Considering that 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999% of the time, I am the only one seeing the password text box, and the 99.99999999999999999999999 % of the time I get it wrong and have to fight/curse it all, this is total blessing to say the least.